# How to view output files from Dataproc job on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, dataproc

How can I view the contents of the output files from my dataproc job?

Is this something I need to change in the code I've written for the dataproc .jar file?

[this is my storage bucket for the output of the job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bxu02.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you download the files to your local computer they can be opened using a text editor program.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I figure out my issue, dataproc is returning me a number instead of the word count my java code produces.

When I run the hadoop job on my local machine it does the word count fine.

Do you have any suggestions why his may not work? thanks